# Hammer.js swipe events not being triggered on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, hammer.js

I'm trying to add swipe gestures to an image carousel, but I'm having issues with Safari on iOS.

My hammer.js initialization looks like this:

```
this.mc = new Hammer.Manager(this.$carousel[0]);
this.mc.add(new Hammer.Swipe({
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL,
    threshold: 0
}));
```

Where `this.$carousel[0]` is the div containing all the images, and the event binding is set like this:

```
this.mc.on('swipeleft', this.slideLeft.bind(this));
this.mc.on('swiperight', this.slideRight.bind(this));
```

However, `this.slideLeft` and `this.slideRight` never get called.

The weird thing is that the same code seems to be working ok on Chrome on different Android versions, and it fails to trigger the `swipe*` events only on Safari on iPhones.

Any ideas about what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in version 2.0.1, the one I was using, where some of the events composing a swipe event were being fired in the wrong order; with version 2.0.6 it seems to be working as expected.